# Laravel groupBy not working , version 5.4.24

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

Here is my query, it works on all older versions.

```
$data = DB::table('applicant')
            ->groupBy('AppAffID')
            ->get();
```

Error i get is :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'comloant_loantreeAPI.applicant.AppID' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `applicant` group by `AppAffID`)
```

I have tried the database change :

I added  'strict' => false, to database config.

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

Comment: Can you show the database config file?

Comment: @Teun , i added it

Comment: Are you sure that you are using mysql? And after changing the config have you cleared the config cache? `php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you want to achieve with the `groupBy`? If you want to sort on the `AppAffID` you should use the `orderBy` instead done like so:

```
$data = DB::table('applicant')
        ->orderBy('AppAffID', 'desc') //can also use 'asc' for ascending
        ->get();
```

Comment: if i use sortBy i get an error : BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortBy()